# Switching Stylesheet dynamically

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

My task is to merge two Pages in one. I work with ASP.NET. While loading, I have to choose an .css, an business object and fill data in the asp:updatePanel. The both sites should show log from two different Devices.

As I understand it, i should switch everything in Page_Load.

I tried to choose the css File in Page_PreInt and Page_Load in the same time, and neither of those worked:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // seting the master page
        switch (deviceOrTerminal) 
        {
            case DeviceOrTerminalEnum.Device:
                this.Master.MasterPageFile = "~/Device/Device.Master";
                Session.Add("style", "/Theme/DeviceEventHistory.css");
                lnkCSS.Attributes["href"] = "/Theme/DeviceEventHistory.css";
                lnkCSS.Attributes["href"] = "~/Theme/DeviceEventHistory.css";
                break;
            case DeviceOrTerminalEnum.Terminal:
                this.Master.MasterPageFile = "~/Terminal/TerminalDetail.Master";
                Session.Add("style", "/Theme/TerminalEventHistory.css");
                lnkCSS.Attributes["href"] = "/Theme/TerminalEventHistory.css";
                lnkCSS.Attributes["href"] = "~/Theme/TerminalEventHistory.css";
                break;
            case DeviceOrTerminalEnum.None:
                this.Master.MasterPageFile = "~/Main.Master";
                Session.Add("style", "/Theme/NoneEventHistory.css");
                lnkCSS.Attributes["href"] = "/EventHistory/Theme/NoneEventHistory.css";
                lnkCSS.Attributes["href"] = "~/EventHistory/Theme/NoneEventHistory.css";
                break;
        }
    }`


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CommandBarTop.TitleCaption = TitleCaption;
        CommandBarGridTop.DisableAllButtons();
        CommandBarGridBottom.DisableAllButtons();
        CommandBarTop.DisableAllButtons();
        CommandBarBottom.DisableAllButtons();
        CommandBarBottom.SetSearchMode(eventHistoryBo.PermissionId);
        CommandBarBottom.SearchClicked += CommandBar_SearchClicked;
        CommandBarBottom.SearchButtonText = (String)GetLocalResourceObject("CommandBar.SearchButton");
        CommandBarTop.SetSearchMode(eventHistoryBo.PermissionId);
        CommandBarTop.SearchClicked += CommandBar_SearchClicked;
        CommandBarTop.SearchButtonText = (String)GetLocalResourceObject("CommandBar.SearchButton");
        String shortDatePattern = PreferredBrowserLanguage.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
        String shortTimePattern = PreferredBrowserLanguage.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern;
        txtEventTimeFrom.CalendarDateFormat = shortDatePattern + " " + shortTimePattern;
        txtEventTimeTo.CalendarDateFormat = shortDatePattern + " " + shortTimePattern;

        String jsValidatorName = "clientValidate";
        Type jsType = GetType();
        if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(jsValidatorName))
        {
            Initialize();
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if ((!TMSPrincipal.IsPermissionOk(deviceBo.PermissionId, EnumPermissionType.View))
                   || (!TMSPrincipal.IsPermissionOk(terminalBo.PermissionId, EnumPermissionType.View)))
                {
                    throw new HttpException("Insufficient permissions to view details.");
                }

                switch (deviceOrTerminal) 
                {
                    case DeviceOrTerminalEnum.Device:
                        CommandBarTop.TitleCaption.Replace(CommandBarTop.TitleCaption.ToString(), "Device");
                        CommandBarGridTop.TitleCaption = "Device";
                        lnkCSS.Attributes["href"] = "/Theme/DeviceEventHistory.css";
                        lnkCSS.Attributes["href"] = "~/Theme/DeviceEventHistory.css";
                        break;
                    case DeviceOrTerminalEnum.Terminal:
                        CommandBarTop.TitleCaption.Replace(CommandBarTop.TitleCaption.ToString(), "Terminal");
                        CommandBarGridTop.TitleCaption = "Terimal";
                        lnkCSS.Attributes["href"] = "/Theme/TerminalEventHistory.css";
                        lnkCSS.Attributes["href"] = "~/Theme/TerminalEventHistory.css";
                        break;
                    case DeviceOrTerminalEnum.None:
                        CommandBarTop.TitleCaption.Replace(CommandBarTop.TitleCaption.ToString(), " ");
                        UserHints.Add(new UserHint(GetLocalResourceObject("Error_DeviceNorTerminal_Title.Text").ToString(), GetLocalResourceObject("Error_DeviceNorTerminal_Body.Text").ToString(), EnumUserHintType.Error));
                        lnkCSS.Attributes["href"] = "/EventHistory/Theme/NoneEventHistory.css";
                        lnkCSS.Attributes["href"] = "~/EventHistory/Theme/NoneEventHistory.css";
                        break;
                }

                txtEventTimeFrom.Text = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-7).ToString("g");
                txtEventTimeTo.Text = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1).ToString("g");
                FillData();
                InitializeDropDownEventType();
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm programming this kind of ASP.NET for 1 Month (before i worked with MVC and Razor), so I would be thankfull for any andvice. I know there are some simmullar questions, but none of those solves my problem.

Comment: Why are you setting `href` twice in each branch of your `case`??

Comment: I thought on of those could work, but didnt.

Comment: Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023923/how-to-render-css-conditionally-in-page

Answer (score 1):

I did a simple test:

**MasterA.Master**

```
...
 <h1>Master A</h1>
...
```

**MasterB.Master**

```
...
 <h1>Master B</h1>
...
```

**Page.aspx**

(`Page.aspx.cs`)

```
public partial class Page : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var letter = HttpContext.Current.Request["m"] != null ?
                     HttpContext.Current.Request["m"] : "A";
        this.MasterPageFile = "~/Master" + letter + ".Master";
    }
}
```

(`Page.aspx`)

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/MasterA.Master" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="Page.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="WebAppWebForms.Page" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <h3>Content</h3>
    <p>Content of the page</p>
</asp:Content>
```

and I got this:

[image]

So you can, as the [docs mention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/specifying-the-master-page-programmatically-cs), change the master page dynamically in the `PreInit` event of the page.

**Now**, the CSS...

If you're changing the master page, why not write the correct CSS file in the master page itself, and all you need to do is simply switch the master page?

And **if you're only switching the master page**, you could script it by using a `ViewSwitcher` as that's what WebForms use when switching masterPages for different devices...

fire up a brand new WebForms project in your Visual Studio, and see how they accomplish that task using the file `ViewSwitcher.ascx`

[image]